# How can I revoke all the permissions a role has in sql server?

Tags: sql-server

I have a role, it has some select perms on various tables. I would like to remove all the select permissions that the role has across all tables. Eg,

```
revoke all from my_role_name;
```

But this doesn't seem to work. How can I do this?

Comment: What does "this doesn't seem to work" mean in detail?

Comment: It doesn't remove the select permissions.

Comment: Check out the output message "The ALL permission is deprecated and maintained only for compatibility. It DOES NOT imply ALL permissions defined on the entity."

Comment: Yes I saw that, but does anyone know of some commands that can achieve what I want?

Comment: Unfortunately T-SQL makes this unnecessarily complicated. You can use `sys.database_permissions` to enumerate the permissions, but then you still need to generate and execute the statements (i.e. some variation on `select formatmessage('REVOKE SELECT ON %s FROM my_role_name;', QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(major_id))) from sys.database_permissions where grantee_principal_id = (select principal_id from sys.database_principals where name = 'my_role_name')`).

Comment: If you truly want to remove all of the permissions, drop the role and recreate it.

Comment: That would work, but I wanted to retain the memberships.

Answer (score 2):

I just had the need to do this.

You can use something along the lines of the below

```
DECLARE @RevokeScript NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @PrincipalName SYSNAME = 'my_role_name'

SELECT @RevokeScript = STRING_AGG(CAST('REVOKE ' + permission_name
                                       + CASE class_desc
                                           WHEN 'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN' THEN ' ON ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)) + '.' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_NAME(major_id))
                                           WHEN 'SCHEMA' THEN ' ON  SCHEMA::' + SCHEMA_NAME(major_id)
                                           WHEN 'DATABASE' THEN ''
                                         END
                                       + ' TO ' + QUOTENAME(@PrincipalName) COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';')
FROM   sys.database_permissions AS pe
WHERE  pe.grantee_principal_id = DATABASE_PRINCIPAL_ID (@PrincipalName);

PRINT @RevokeScript

EXEC (@RevokeScript)
```